# HBase master not running exception

Tags: hadoop, hbase, nutch, gora

I am getting following error. I am trying to connect HBase as a back-end for Nutch crawler.

```
13/10/21 13:11:13 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: getMaster attempt 0 of 10 failed; retrying after sleep of 1000
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:357)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:94)
        at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:109)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.initializeDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:102)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:161)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:135)
        at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.createWebStore(StorageUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:221)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:251)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:273)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:282)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
13/10/21 13:11:14 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: ZooKeeper available but no active master location found
13/10/21 13:11:14 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: getMaster attempt 1 of 10 failed; retrying after sleep of 1000
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:357)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:94)
        at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:109)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.initializeDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:102)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:161)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:135)
        at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.createWebStore(StorageUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:221)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:251)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:273)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:282)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
13/10/21 13:11:15 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: ZooKeeper available but no active master location found
13/10/21 13:11:15 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: getMaster attempt 2 of 10 failed; retrying after sleep of 1000
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:357)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:94)
        at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:109)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.initializeDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:102)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:161)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:135)
        at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.createWebStore(StorageUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:221)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:251)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:273)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:282)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
13/10/21 13:11:16 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: ZooKeeper available but no active master location found
13/10/21 13:11:16 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: getMaster attempt 3 of 10 failed; retrying after sleep of 2000
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:357)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:94)
        at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:109)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.initializeDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:102)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:161)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:135)
        at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.createWebStore(StorageUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:221)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:251)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:273)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:282)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
13/10/21 13:11:18 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: ZooKeeper available but no active master location found
13/10/21 13:11:18 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: getMaster attempt 4 of 10 failed; retrying after sleep of 2000
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:357)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:94)
        at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:109)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.initializeDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:102)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:161)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:135)
        at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.createWebStore(StorageUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:221)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:251)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:273)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:282)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
13/10/21 13:11:20 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: ZooKeeper available but no active master location found
13/10/21 13:11:20 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: getMaster attempt 5 of 10 failed; retrying after sleep of 4000
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:357)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:94)
        at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:109)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.initializeDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:102)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:161)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:135)
        at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.createWebStore(StorageUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:221)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:251)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:273)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:282)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
13/10/21 13:11:24 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: ZooKeeper available but no active master location found
13/10/21 13:11:24 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: getMaster attempt 6 of 10 failed; retrying after sleep of 4000
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:357)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:94)
        at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:109)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.initializeDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:102)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:161)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:135)
        at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.createWebStore(StorageUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:221)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:251)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:273)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:282)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
13/10/21 13:11:28 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: ZooKeeper available but no active master location found
13/10/21 13:11:28 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: getMaster attempt 7 of 10 failed; retrying after sleep of 8000
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:357)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:94)
        at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:109)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.initializeDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:102)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:161)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:135)
        at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.createWebStore(StorageUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:221)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:251)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:273)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:282)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
13/10/21 13:11:36 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: ZooKeeper available but no active master location found
13/10/21 13:11:36 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: getMaster attempt 8 of 10 failed; retrying after sleep of 16000
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:357)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:94)
        at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:109)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.initializeDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:102)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:161)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:135)
        at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.createWebStore(StorageUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:221)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:251)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:273)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:282)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
13/10/21 13:11:52 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: ZooKeeper available but no active master location found
13/10/21 13:11:52 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: getMaster attempt 9 of 10 failed; no more retrying.
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:357)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:94)
        at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:109)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.initializeDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:102)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:161)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:135)
        at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.createWebStore(StorageUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:221)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:251)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:273)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:282)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
13/10/21 13:11:52 ERROR crawl.InjectorJob: InjectorJob: org.apache.gora.util.GoraException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:167)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:135)
        at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.createWebStore(StorageUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:221)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:251)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:273)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:282)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException
        at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:127)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.initializeDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:102)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:161)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:394)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:94)
        at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:109)
```

Please help me.

Comment: I had similar exception `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException` when calling `list` from hbase shell!!

Answer (score 1):

It seems your HBase Master is not running. Execute `$ jps` to see if you have HMaster running.

Answer (score 1):

Correction. By mistake I had written wrong host name in hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
     <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
     <value>hdfs://hadoop:9000/hbase</value>  // the actual host name was hadoop1
  </property>
```